# Issue using `totcount` to create a score counter per-exam question

Tags: counters, auxiliary-files, totcount

On the cover sheet of an exam, I want to generate a tabulation of the questions and their point totals. (This is part of a package I'm writing. I am aware of `exam.sty`, but it doesn't suit me.) I have a loop that generates the table, but in my MWE below, I just tabulate manually: the problem is in the aux file.

I am trying to use `totcount`. It works fine for keeping track of the number of questions and a tally of points, but I can not make it record each question's point total in the aux.

NB: I'm not above just using a `\def` to keep the scores of questions, but the idea is that I want to be able to add sub-questions which increment the question's counter.

**My Questions**

1. Is there a better approach than in the below MWE
2. What is going wrong?
3. If I'm not to abandon this approach, how do I fix it?

---

### MWE

In the below MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{totcount}

\newcounter{questioncount}
\setcounter{questioncount}{0}
\regtotcounter{questioncount}%
\newcounter{scoretotal}
\setcounter{scoretotal}{0}
\regtotcounter{scoretotal}%

\newcommand{\setquestionpoints}[2]{%
  \global\expandafter\newtotcounter{qpoints#1}%
  \global\expandafter\setcounter{qpoints#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\getquestionpoints}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{qpoints#1}>0
    \arabic{qpoints#1}%
  \else
    0%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\nquestion}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{questioncount}%
  \setquestionpoints{\thequestioncount}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{scoretotal}{#1}%
  Question~\thequestioncount (#1 marks.)%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r@{:\quad}l}
    Number of Questions & \total{questioncount} \\
    Total points        & \total{scoretotal} \\
    Question 1 max      & \total{qpoints1} \\
    Question 2 max      & \total{qpoints2} \\
    Question 3 max      & \total{qpoints3} \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2cm}

\nquestion{10}

\nquestion{12}

\nquestion{15}

\end{document}
```

the point total of the final question is simply recorded with the multiplicity of the number of questions. In that specific case of 3 questions, the aux file reads:

```
\relax 
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@questioncount@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{questioncount@totc}\fi\setcounter{questioncount@totc}{3}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@scoretotal@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{scoretotal@totc}\fi\setcounter{scoretotal@totc}{37}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@qpoints3@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{qpoints3@totc}\fi\setcounter{qpoints3@totc}{15}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@qpoints3@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{qpoints3@totc}\fi\setcounter{qpoints3@totc}{15}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@qpoints3@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{qpoints3@totc}\fi\setcounter{qpoints3@totc}{15}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

and the document (and log) reflect the absence of `qpoints1` and `qpoints2`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\global\expandafter` does nothing useful. You need to expand the argument before passing it to `\newtotcounter` and `\setcounter`.

You also need to cope with the possibly not yet existing counters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{totcount}

\newcounter{questioncount}
\setcounter{questioncount}{0}
\regtotcounter{questioncount}%
\newcounter{scoretotal}
\setcounter{scoretotal}{0}
\regtotcounter{scoretotal}%

\newcommand{\setquestionpoints}[2]{%
  \expanded{\noexpand\newtotcounter{qpoints#1}}%
  \expanded{\noexpand\setcounter{qpoints#1}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\getquestionpoints}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{qpoints#1}>0
    \arabic{qpoints#1}%
  \else
    0%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\nquestion}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{questioncount}%
  \setquestionpoints{\arabic{questioncount}}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{scoretotal}{#1}%
  Question~\thequestioncount (#1 marks.)%
}

\newcommand{\TOTAL}[1]{%
  \ifcsname c@#1@totc\endcsname
    \total{#1}%
  \else
    ??%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r@{:\quad}l}
    Number of Questions & \TOTAL{questioncount} \\
    Total points        & \TOTAL{scoretotal} \\
    Question 1 max      & \TOTAL{qpoints1} \\
    Question 2 max      & \TOTAL{qpoints2} \\
    Question 3 max      & \TOTAL{qpoints3} \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2cm}

\nquestion{10}

\nquestion{12}

\nquestion{15}

\end{document}
```

After two runs you'll get

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure I understand, correct me if/where I'm wrong. In my original, the call `\setquestionpoints{\thequestioncount}{#1}` in `\nquestion`, the first argument, `\thequestioncount` was not immediately expanded in `\setquestionpoints`. It was being expanded at the end of the document once `questioncount` was '3' and thus I was getting the multiplicity. If that's right, can you point me toward the rule that explains why expansion was so delayed?

Comment: FYI, the `\global\expandafter` was an artifact of where I left off with ChatGPT, which was worse than useless :)  I was closer to the answer before I started with it: I had guessed it was a matter of when things were being expanded but ChatGPT insisted it had to do with scope, which was demonstrably false since I was getting output to the aux. But I was tired and desperate, and would have tried anything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Timtro You've learned that “answers” by ChatGPT are plain rubbish.