# Expl3 to simplify expansion issues with loop-built Tabularray content

Tags: expl3, loops, tabularray, for-loop

A follow-on from [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/705586/19569) answered thanks to @egreg. (Perhaps Prof. Gregorio would be able to help me here too.)

#### Situation

I am creating a Table of Questions (ToQ) macro for creating marking table on the cover of an exam or assignment. It was working fine with `tabular` but I switched to Tabularray's `tblr`, which I am falling in love with. Unfortunately, because I use `totcount` to create counters for the grades in each new question as they are encountered, I run into issues of expansion that have stumped me today.

#### Problem

Loops cannot be put inside a `tblr` environment (see [§3.2.3](https://muug.ca/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) of the manual), as is the case with ordinary tabulars. But the solutions that seem to work for ordinary tabulars:

- using LaTeX primitive loops,
- building the body outside the table as a \gdef made of \edefs, and
- building the body as a token register,

have not worked for `tblr`. Additionally, `tblr` allows one to specify an `expand` option to specify tokens for expansion before it processes the body. (I will show this in the later MWE.)

#### What I would like

Inspired by @frougon's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648916/19569), I would like to take a completely expl3 approach, since I am trying to learn expl3 anyway. But I'm in over my head, and would appreciate some help. Not merely a solution, if you could be so kind, I would like a brief outline so that I can study the solution by crawling the docs.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{totcount}

% Stuff for keeping account of questions and their scores
% ........................................................<<<
\newcounter{questioncount}
\setcounter{questioncount}{0}
\regtotcounter{questioncount}%
\newcounter{scoretotal}
\setcounter{scoretotal}{0}
\regtotcounter{scoretotal}%

\newcommand{\setquestionpoints}[2]{%
  \expanded{\noexpand\newtotcounter{qpoints#1}}%
  \expanded{\noexpand\setcounter{qpoints#1}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\getquestionpoints}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{qpoints#1}>0
    \arabic{qpoints#1}%
  \else
    0%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\TOTAL}[1]{%
  \ifcsname c@#1@totc\endcsname
    \total{#1}%
  \else
    ??%
  \fi
}
% ........................................................>>>

% Typesetting questions
% ........................................................<<<
\newcommand{\nquestion}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{questioncount}%
  \setquestionpoints{\arabic{questioncount}}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{scoretotal}{#1}%
  Question~\thequestioncount (#1 marks.)%
}
% ........................................................>>>

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_typeset_table_generic:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
      \cs_set_protected:Npn \__my_typeset_table_generic_tmp_func:n ##1 {#1}
      \__my_typeset_table_generic_tmp_func:n {#2}
    \group_end:
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_typeset_table_generic:nn { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% This works, but I would like to know how expl3 can help me build this
%  list automatically, looping for
%      q ∈ [1, \totvalue{questioncount}]
%  to obtain \TOTAL{qpoints\theq} in each cell of the middle column.
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tabular_tl {%
    1 & \TOTAL{qpoints1} & \null \\ \hline
    2 & \TOTAL{qpoints2} & \null \\ \hline
    3 & \TOTAL{qpoints3} & \null \\ \hline
}
\my_typeset_table_generic:nV
  {
    \SetTblrInner{rowsep=1ex}%
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={|ccX[c]|}, width=0.35\linewidth}
      \SetRow{black, rowsep=0.25ex}
      \color{white}\textit{Q}\textnumero & \color{white}Marks & \color{white}Grade \\ \hline
      #1
    \SetCell[c=2]{c}~TOTAL:~&~\null\\\cline[r]{3-3}
           && {\TOTAL{scoretotal}}\\\hline
    \end{tblr}
  }
  \l_my_tabular_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%% Make some questions:
\vspace{2cm}
\noindent
\nquestion{10}\\
\nquestion{12}\\
\nquestion{15}\\


\end{document}
```

Produces:

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution wherein I build the lines of a macro in expl3. I don't think it's the most elegant, but it works. I'm interested in tips/comments to improve it, so I'm leaving this answer un-accepted to see if someone slides in with something beautiful.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ToQ}{}{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {
    \SetTblrInner{rowsep=1ex}%
    \begin{tblr}[b]{colspec={|ccX[c]|}, width=0.35\linewidth}
      \SetRow{black, rowsep=0.25ex}
      \color{white}\textit{Q}\textnumero
        & \color{white}Marks
          & \color{white}Grade \\ \hline
  }
  \int_step_inline:nn {\totvalue{questioncount}} {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 & \fromaux{qpoints##1} & \null \\ \hline }
  }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {
      \SetCell[c=2]{c}~TOTAL:~&~\null\\\cline[r]{3-3}
      && {\fromaux{scoretotal}}\\\hline
    \end{tblr}
  }
  \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Produces

[image]

Comment: @Timro  Please see my solution.

Answer (score 3):

The last `\\` after `\nquestion{15}` caused a Badbox so it is removed.

The `tblr` environment can be put outside the expl3 code. The option `expand` in the `tblr` environment is used. Then `\my_typeset_table_generic:nn` is not needed anymore.

In the `tblr` environment, the option `rowsep=1ex` is placed in the options list, the settings for the first row are determined with the key `row{1}`. Then it is unnecessary to write `\color{white}` three times.

The macro `\null` is removed.

Braces around `\TOTAL{scoretotal}` are removed.

In the command `\nquestion`, `{}` is added after `\thequestioncount` so that the parentheses do not immediately follow after the number.

The macro `\l_my_tabular_tl` was not initialized with `\tl_new:N`. This is now done with `\tl_new:N \tblrbody`.

The content is collected with `\tl_build_put_right:Nn`. This process is started with `\tl_build_begin:N` and ended with `\tl_build_end:N`.

It is unnecessary to put `\setcounter{questioncount}{0}` after `\newcounter{questioncount}` because the initial value is already 0.

Instead of using `\newcounter` and `\regtotcounter`, the shorthand `\newtotcounter` can be used.

It is unnecessary to define the command `\TOTAL`. This is replaced by `\total`.

The command `\setquestionpoints` is integrated in the command `\nquestion`. Here, `\arabic{questioncount}` is replaced by `\thequestioncount`. For `\setcounter`, `\expanded` and `\noexpand` are unnecessary.

After `\SetCell`, an `&` is added because using `\SetCell`, omitted cells must not be removed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{totcount}

% Stuff for keeping account of questions and their scores
% ........................................................<<<
\newtotcounter{questioncount}
\newtotcounter{scoretotal}

\newcommand{\getquestionpoints}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{qpoints#1}>0
    \arabic{qpoints#1}%
  \else
    0%
  \fi
}

% ........................................................>>>

% Typesetting questions
% ........................................................<<<
\newcommand{\nquestion}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{questioncount}%
  \expanded{\noexpand\newtotcounter{qpoints\thequestioncount}}%
  \setcounter{qpoints\thequestioncount}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{scoretotal}{#1}%
  Question~\thequestioncount{} (#1 marks.)%
}
% ........................................................>>>


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \tblrbody
\tl_build_begin:N \tblrbody
\int_step_inline:nn { \totvalue { questioncount } }
  {
    \tl_build_put_right:Nn \tblrbody { #1 & \total { qpoints#1 } & \\ \hline }
  }
\tl_build_end:N \tblrbody
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{tblr}[expand=\tblrbody]{
  colspec={|ccX[c]|},
  width=0.35\linewidth,
  rowsep=1ex,
  row{1}={bg=black,fg=white,rowsep=0.25ex}
}
\emph{Q}\textnumero & Marks & Grade\\\hline
\tblrbody
\SetCell[c=2]{c} ~TOTAL:~ & & \\\cline[r]{3-3}
 & & \total{scoretotal}\\\hline
\end{tblr}


%%% Make some questions:
\vspace{2cm}
\noindent
\nquestion{10}\\
\nquestion{12}\\
\nquestion{15}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Life does not have to be that complicated. Always start specifying how you want the input to be and how the output. That is provide an API.

1. You do not need the LaTeX2e counters, use the `int` module.
2. When you want to store values, think of `csname`.
3. Create a series of commands `\Q1`..`\Qn` storing the value as `\Q1-marks` if you want you could have a `\Q1-question` to store the actual question as well.

Here is a quick solution. I have used tabular, just to demonstrate the concepts. As a rule I try to minimize the packages I use. Please modify to add prefixes to the l3 commands, as is good practice.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
%------------------------------------------------------------
% INPUT : \AddQuestion{name}{marks}
% OUTPUT: PrintScoreSheet  
%------------------------------------------------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g_questions_total_int
\clist_new:N \g_questions_clist
\prop_new:N \g_questions_marks_prop
\cs_new_protected:Npn \questions_add:nn  #1 #2
  {
    \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_questions_clist {#1}
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_questions_marks_prop {#1} {#2}
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \questions_printlist:
  {
    \begin{tabular}{lrr}
      \hline
      \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_questions_clist
        {
          \prop_get:NnN \g_questions_marks_prop {##1} \l_tmpa_tl
          \int_gadd:Nn \g_questions_total_int { \l_tmpa_tl } 
           ##1  &  \use:c{##1-marks} &\\  %Row
        }
      \\\noalign{\vskip-10pt}
      \cline{2-3} 
      Total & \int_use:N\g_questions_total_int &\\ 
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  }
\let\AddQuestion\questions_add:nn
\let\PrintScoreSheet\questions_printlist:

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\AddQuestion {Q1}{10}
\AddQuestion {Q2}{20}
\AddQuestion {Q3}{5}
\AddQuestion{Q4}{5}
\PrintScoreSheet
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would have been nice if you had followed the expl3 naming scheme.

Comment: To explain what @UlrikeFischer means: variable names should contain a scope (`\g_questions_total_int`), and functions should have the module part first (so `\questions_add:nn` using `questions` as your module).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  I specifically tried to make it less confusing for the OP and made a note for him to add it and use prefixes to his like.

Comment: @Skillmon I am aware. See my note to Ulrike. I find people understand things better if they are grammatical, is wired in our brains!

Comment: @Skillmon I guess I should edt it:)  Would appreciate if you do, as well as add the image, as it keeps failing when I try to do it.

Comment: It is much easier to get familiar with a programming language if examples stick to the standard and not everyone invents their own dialect.  I find your code confusing as it is unclear which variables are local and which global and which commands are meant to be internal. Btw: you should use \cs_new_protected: as your commands contain non expandable commands.

Comment: Thank you. I have found your solution edifying, clean and clear. It unfortunately doesn't stash the question values in an aux file so that they can be retrieved on a second pass for the grading sheet to appear on the cover of the exam. I agree that my MWE has a lot of accidental complexity owing to my confusion in the matter and artifacts of growing pain.

Comment: @Timtro  Why do you need a secoond pass? You can add fields as many as you want including the actual question text, answer and marks awarded, student name, number etc, in a single pass! To be honest if I had to do this in a classroom, I would do it with lua+l3  so I can sort student names and grades alphabetically etc.  And Ulrike is right you should follow l3 conventions. I didnt and regret it to be honest, as answers should be exemplary. I might come back after the holidays and post a full exam sample.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I'm quite intrigued by your single-pass concept. Am I missing something, or would I have to define/store all of the questions and then automate their typesetting after the cover page? Anyway, I would love to see your comprehensive exam solution. I'm going to be working on mine over the holidays, so maybe we can compare. Are you able to work with Git+GitHub/GitLab? Perhaps we could collaborate and have a CTAN package fall out.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I've fixed your naming conventions (if there was no stupid oversight), I've also used a `prop`-list instead of some custom cs-names to store away the marks, I think this is cleaner. What I'm not particularly fond of in your answer is the need for the space hack with `\noalign{\vskip-10pt}` to get around the fact that you're introducing an additional `\\ ` because your loop doesn't allow a trailing `\omit` (note that those `10pt` don't work reliably, you'd get wrong spacing rather easily). That's fixable by an expandable loop, or building the table body outside `tabular`.

Comment: @Skillmon thanks and appreciated. What version of `l3` do you have? On mine (latest) I have to use ``\cs_new_protected:Npn` not as you have shown.`. I am not too sure if the sugar coating of `prop` is cleaner as it obscures the underlying structure. At least for old toppies like myself that we are used to `TeX`, but is is a great effort by the l3 Team and we should accept it and help newcomers to the new structures.

Comment: Whoops, some hickup on my end. Of course it should've been `\cs_new_protected:Npn`, my bad, will fix it. But the difference between many `cs`-names and a `prop` is, that the `prop` only uses a single macro underneath. It turns out a bit slower than many `cs` for accessing the contents (especially if you need expandable access, as then you get O(n) instead of O(1) speed), but it doesn't clutter the namespace and additionally you can loop over a `prop` without a second data storage (but the keys/names in a `prop` can't be used for typesetting).